# How to remove guzzle/guzzle package?

Tags: json, composer-php, omnipay, guzzle

I need install omnipay package for laravel.

```
composer require ignited/laravel-omnipay
```

During the installation of the package received an error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

With list a problems:

```
  Problem 1
- Installation request for ignited/laravel-omnipay ^2.3 -> satisfiable by ignited/laravel-omnipay[2.3.0].
- Conclusion: remove guzzle/guzzle v3.8.1
- Conclusion: don't install guzzle/guzzle v3.8.1
- ignited/laravel-omnipay 2.3.0 requires omnipay/common 2.5.* -> satisfiable by omnipay/common[2.5.2, v2.5.0, v2.5.1].
- omnipay/common 2.5.2 requires guzzle/guzzle ~3.9 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2, v3.9.3].
- omnipay/common v2.5.0 requires guzzle/guzzle ~3.9 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2, v3.9.3].
- omnipay/common v2.5.1 requires guzzle/guzzle ~3.9 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2, v3.9.3].
- Can only install one of: guzzle/guzzle[v3.9.0, v3.8.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzle/guzzle[v3.9.1, v3.8.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzle/guzzle[v3.9.2, v3.8.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzle/guzzle[v3.9.3, v3.8.1].
- Installation request for guzzle/guzzle (locked at v3.8.1) -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.8.1].
```

And composer.json reverting back:

> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

How to delete annoying package?

I already tried yo remove it through:

```
 composer remove guzzle/guzzle
```

But not a successful, and of couse i install guzzlehttp/guzzle package instead guzzle/guzzle.

How to clear my composer repositories of guzzle/guzzle package?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.

Reason:

The guzzle/guzzle package (*deprecated*) is required for league/flysystem-rackspace.

Therefore we should be remove this package.

```
composer remove league/flysystem-rackspace
```